# Calculating on Lookup column without the use of SharePoint Designer?

Tags: list, infopath, lookup-column, calculated-column

Trying to find a way to join values in two separate columns into a third however one of these is a lookup field to a second list and as I understand you cannot do calculations on lookups without using SharePoint Designer.

For reasons unknown to me (and which cannot be changed) SharePoint Designer cannot be used with the site in question so wanting to see if there was an alternative solution maybe using InfoPath.

I have the following lists:-

**ListActions**

- ActionName : Single Line of Text
- ActionNumber : Single Line of Text

**ListSubActions**

- SubActionName : Single Line of Text
- SubActionNumber : Single Line of Text
- RelatedAction : Lookup [ListActions:ActionName, ActionName:ActionNumber]
- SubActionFullRef : Calculated (Ideally appending the SubActionNumber to the ActionNumber]

Is there a way to calculate ‘**SubActionFullRef**’?

Any pointers/ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `InfoPath` is an alternative solution to concatenate your fields!

**Steps,**

- From the above ribbon, > Click on `Customize Form` via InfoPath.
- In Your form > click on the Lookup field to select it.
- From the above ribbon > Home Tab > Click on `Add Rules` > `This field changes` > `Set Field Value`.

[image]

- At `Rule Details`  > Select the field that will hold the concatenation value.
- Add value > Click on **Fx** button.
- Click on insert function button > Select **concat** function.
- Add your lookup field and your other field.

[image]

- Publish your form.
- Now the concatenation field would hold the correct value when the lookup up field changed!

---

**Check also**

- [The supported and unsupported columns in SharePoint calculated column formula](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)
- [Using lookup field in SharePoint calculated column formula](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/lookup-field-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)